# -moz-scrollbars-vertical equivalent for Chrome/Opera/Safari?

Tags: css, scrollbar

IE6, IE7, and IE8 display a vertical scroll bar for the page by default even if it is not scrollable.  Chrome and Firefox do not do this (I'm assuming Opera and Safari do not as well).  You can accomplish this same behavior in FireFox using the CSS:

```
body { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; }
```

Is there any way to force the visible scrollbar in the other three browsers?  Or even better, a standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update

You may (in addition) need to include `-ms-overflow-y` and/or `-moz-scrollbars-vertical`, as mentioned in [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389979/force-vertical-scrollbar-to-display-in-ie8):

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; /* For FF */
    -ms-overflow-y: scroll; /* For IE */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* For others & old IE */
}
```

---

## Original

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

See ["overflow-y" at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Tested & verified (successfully) in:

- FF 7
- Chrome 15
- IE 5+6+7+8+9+10(platform preview) w/[IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)
- Opera 11.52
- Safari/Win 5.1.1

### Full example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html { overflow-y: scroll; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    Test content
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
html { height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px; }
```

See [Forcing scrollbars (now even better)](http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/forcing-scrollbars-now-even-better) for more information.

Comment: Not sure why I left this for so long, but that trick doesn't seem to work in FireFox (so it would need to be coupled with the overflow hack).  Is there nothing even in CSS3/HTML5 about showing vertical scroll bars in the main document? =[

Comment: replacing margin-bottom with padding-bottom makes this one still work, at least in FF (although the slack of 1px is not elegant)