# Website jumps from side to side?

Tags: sticky-footer, vertical-scrolling

When people navigate my website the pages jump from side to side. It is caused by some pages not having sufficient content to cause the vertical scroll bar to appear. Other than trying pad out the pages unnecessarily, is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to force the scrollbar.

[Force vertical scrollbar to display in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389979/force-vertical-scrollbar-to-display-in-ie8)